# sprint namedParameterJdbcTemplate batchUpdate with in clause

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using spring to insert batch records into the DB. But I am getting this error: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert between java.util.ArrayList and JAVA_OBJECT.
can you please help what am I doing wrong

```
private static final String INSERT_BATCH_QUERY ="INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID,TEST_ID) select :id,  substring((SELECT ', ' + USERS.COMMON_NAME FROM USERS WHERE USERS.ID IN ( :testIds ) FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 4000);


public class Test{

private int id;
private List<Intenger> testIds;
    //**getters and setters**//
}

public static void Main(String... args){
        List<Test> myTe=new ....
        SqlParameterSource[] sqlParameterSource = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(myTe.toArray());
        result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT_BATCH_QUERY, sqlParameterSource); 
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert between java.util.ArrayList and JAVA_OBJECT.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Support.convert(Support.java:633)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setObjectBase(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:590)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setObject(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:907)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.setObject(PreparedStatementHandle.java:909)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:426)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchUpdateUtils.setStatementParameters(BatchUpdateUtils.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.access$000(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:32)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils$1.setValues(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:48)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:989)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    ... 26 more
```

If I use hard-coded values:

```
private static final String INSERT_BATCH_QUERY ="INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID,TEST_ID) select :id,  substring((SELECT ', ' + USERS.COMMON_NAME FROM USERS WHERE USERS.ID IN ( 1234,654,55 ) FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 4000);
```

or when I pass only one int it's working.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the SqlParameterSource to define the params so that the query will replace the placeholders
`SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("testIds", testIds).addValue("id", id);`